# Среда разработки SQLite, какая больше всего подходит под android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Можете подсказать удобный для андроид разработки менеджер SQlite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для работы с базой в Windows:

1. [SQLite Studio](http://sqlitestudio.pl/)
2. [SQLite Database Browser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/)

Для работы с базой в Android:

1. [SQLite Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xuecs.sqlitemanager&hl=ru)
2. [SQLite Viewer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kokufu.android.apps.sqliteviewer.free&hl=ru)

Для работы с базой в Linux:

1. [SQLite Studio](http://sqlitestudio.pl/)
2. [SQLite Database Browser](http://sqlitebrowser.org/)

**P.S:** Лично я использую [SQLite Studio](http://sqlitestudio.pl/). Все есть, удобно. Нареканий нет

Answer (score 2):

Единственный удобный для разработки менеджер БД, который я знаю, входит в состав продукта IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate в виде плагина Database Support. Данный плагин позволяет прямое подключение к БД проекта прямо на устройстве, где запущено приложение, что конечно же очень удобно, плагин обладает всем необходимым для менеджера БД функционалом (смотрите описание DataGrip).

Из менджеров, которые работают с заранее извлеченной базой данных лично меня больше всего устраивает [SQLite Expert Personal](http://www.sqliteexpert.com/download.html) (freeware) - довольно мощный инструмент со всеми необходимыми функциями за спасибо.

Нельзя не вспомнить про [DataGrip](https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/) - мощная [IDE](https://habrahabr.ru/company/JetBrains/blog/273469/) для работы с SQL базами данных от JetBrains.  По факту этот продукт является самостоятельной реализацией плагина Database Support из IDEA Ultimate, но теряет главное - прямое подключение к БД проекта (распространяется по подписке)